# How can I use a real Application object with Android's ServiceTestCase

Tags: android, testing, servicetestcase

I'm trying to test a service that requires a real Application object, not the MockApplication that the ServiceTestCase provides.

How can I create a real Application object in my ServiceTestCase?

Answer (score 0):

A service has two inherent dependencies, its `Context` and its associated `Application`. The `ServiceTestCase` framework allows you to inject these dependencies, and thus perform unit tests with controlled dependencies in an isolated environment.

You should not use the real `Application` in your tests, but if you know what you are doing you can inject it using [ServiceTestCase.setApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html#setApplication%28android.app.Application%29).

Comment: I got that far alright.  I've been able see where you can inject both of these, I simply can't see how to create either a real Application object (as opposed to the MockApplication that comes with ServiceTestCase) or an Application object in a ContextWrapper (similar to methods available in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2).  I went so far as to attempt creating an ApplicationTestCase as an inner class to the ServiceTestCase.  None of these approaches work.  I'm attempting to test my service's set/update of the system notifications, and the OS needs a real Application to function.